# Field Mapping Examples

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Using ArcGIS 10.4, arcpy

I am having trouble understanding field mappings and the esri examples aren't helping at all.  When I use model builder the field mappings make sense, but I need to customize them more.  I can successfully take the ObjectID field,add it to my new feature class with the input data from the old, but that is the only field that comes in. Is there a way to add all the others instead of going one by one? It seems like it should be so simple, I tried the (addtable) but that is where I am lost.

My end game is to keep ObjectID in my new feature class, I want everything else the same (Type, Length, etc).  Right now on my 'FeatureClasstoFeatureClass' all I can keep with the field mappings is ObjectID.  I could join it up and rexport but field mapping seems like it should be the easiest.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/fieldmappings.htm

I am looking at the examples here.  They only mention adding two fields, but what about every field.

Comment: Field mappings in arcpy are confusing. What do you mean by "My end game is to keep ObjectID in my new feature class, I want everything else the same (Type, Length, etc)."? If you want everything the same you dont need to use field mapping. It is optional and no field mapping = no changes

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can use field mapping in a function to return a feature layer with only specified fields visible:

```
import arcpy

def get_fl_with_optional_fields(in_fc, fieldlist):
    fc_desc = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
    fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,fc_desc.baseName)
    src_field_info = arcpy.Describe(fl).fieldInfo
    for field in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]:
        field_idx = src_field_info.findfieldbyname(field)
        if field in fieldlist:
            src_field_info.setVisible(field_idx,'VISIBLE')
        else:
            src_field_info.setVisible(field_idx,'HIDDEN')
    newfl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,in_fc+'_fl',field_info=src_field_info)
    return newfl

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features=get_fl_with_optional_fields(r'C:\data.gdb\polygon123',['SomeFieldName','SomeFieldName2']), out_path=r'C:\data.gdb', 
                                           out_name='newpolygons')
```